# Any opinion on Samepage as an alternative to Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, intranet, collaboration, file-sharing

I'm hoping someone out there has used both [Samepage.io](https://www.samepage.io/sharepoint-alternative) and Microsoft SharePoint and can tell me what the main differences are, especially when it comes to using it as a team or project collaboration tool, but occasionally as a web publishing platform.

Comment: 1. Are You limited to MS .NET world, or can accept Java / Python / PHP solutions too? 2. because You give question at Stack Overflow, assume You are looking from programmers point of view?

Comment: Im not athodox, but general network / admin / web questions have place at different child sites on Stack Exchange

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Discussion moved here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84283/samepage-io-as-a-sharepoint-alternative

Answer (score 0):

From the feature video I looked at Samepage site it looks like a way to collaborate on common tasks. Where as SharePoint provides a lot more than and definitely SharePoint is much more costlier.

Samepage provides a subset of SharePoint features which is Collaboration if that is only you need it looks like value for money.

But if you are looking for something which provides collaboration, search, enterprise social capabilities (yammer), intranet, video Sharing platform, metadata tagging etc. I think SharePoint is a great platform for that.